# how to set suds schema loction while wsdl doesn't contain one

Tags: python, soap, xsd, wsdl, suds

I'm using suds library (Version 4.0) in python as soap client
the wsdl has no schema location defined in it but the vendor gave us some xsd files.
Now I'm trying to set suds client for a url and a local schema. Can I do that?
I have seen a lot of things explained using Import and ImportDoctor but I do not really understand if it is related to my case. I want something like this..

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "https://someurl?WSDL"
schemaLocation = "/some/local/Location/file.xsd"
client = Client(url,schemaLocation)
```

I know this is wrong but how can I achieve something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
url = "/some/local/Location/file.xsd" #xsd local location
new_url = "https://someurl?WSDL" #service url
c = Client(url)
c.sd[0].service.setlocation(new_url)
```